# bokeh - python - propagate selection on different image by image coordinates

Tags: python, bokeh

I import different layers of a matrix and I display each layer in an image using bokeh.

here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import pickle as pk
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import BoxSelectTool, LassoSelectTool, CrosshairTool, HoverTool, ColorBar, LinearColorMapper

data = pk.load(open('matrix.p','rb'))
labels = pk.load(open('names.p','rb'))

TOOLS="box_select,lasso_select,reset,crosshair,hover"

output_file("bokeh_test.html", title="pictures selection")

# create plots

figs = []
for i in range(len(labels)):
    fig = figure(title=labels[i],tools=TOOLS,sizing_mode="stretch_both",tooltips=[("x", "$x"), ("y", "$y"), ("value", "@image")])
    fig.x_range.range_padding = fig.y_range.range_padding = 0
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette="Turbo256", low=np.amin(data[:,:,i]), high=np.amax(data[:,:,i]))
    fig.image(image=[data[:,:,i]], x=0, y=0, dw=30, dh=10, color_mapper=color_mapper, level="image")
    color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=12, location=(0,0))
    fig.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
    fig.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.axis.visible = False
    fig.toolbar.logo = None
    figs.append(fig)
    
# make a grid
grid = gridplot([[figs[0],figs[1],figs[2]], [figs[3],figs[4],figs[5]]], sizing_mode="stretch_both",merge_tools=True,toolbar_options={'logo': None})
show(grid, sizing_mode='scale_height')
```

and here is the result:
[image: matrix layers]

first question: selection tools have no actions on images. The selection overlay don't appear. any fix ?

second question: when I select one region, for example the top left pixel, I would like it select the top left pixel on every image. But I found no examples on how to propagate selection on pictures. Any suggestion ?